# C#: String split returning list of strings AND list of delimiters?

Tags: c#, string, split

Is there any inbuilt way in C# to split a text into an array of words and delimiters?
What I want is:

```
text = "word1 + word2 - word3";
string[] words = text.Split(new char[] { '+', '-'});
//Need list '+', '-' here?
```

Any ideas? Obviously I can just process the text by hand... :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your post to show what the output in the words array should be for your input example.

Comment: The words array would contain exactly what Split() normally returns,
e.g words = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}  
additionally I am looking for delims = {'+','-'}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Regex.split() with capturing parentheses http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byy2946e.aspx

```
string input = @"07/14/2007";   
string pattern = @"(-)|(/)";

foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern)) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result);
}
// In .NET 1.0 and 1.1, the method returns an array of
// 3 elements, as follows:
//    '07'
//    '14'
//    '2007'
//
// In .NET 2.0, the method returns an array of
// 5 elements, as follows:
//    '07'
//    '/'
//    '14'
//    '/'
//    '2007'
```

Comment: Hopefully you're using .Net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, but I suppose you could do it with a regular expression. Just write it to pick up only your delimiters and then use `Regex.Matches` and the collection that is returned should contain the delimiters. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) for more info including a short sample.